# Should cash bounties be allowed?

Tags: feature-request

StackExchange could make extra money by allowing bounties on prior art questions. If a company like Samsung really wants to foil a competitor, they could throw a fraction of the cost of a lawyer at an Ask Patent prior art question. After either an accepted answer, or x amount of upvotes, or the patent was found to be invalidated, the bounty would be paid out with StackExchange taking a share.

Comment: There are commercial sites set up for that. I'd hate to see this  venue end up effectively  taking sides in the smart phone wars.